# Moodle - DB information

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to change a plugin and need to find out where the database keeps information display tasks in Moodle, the plugin is the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded the moodle on a host, you can login to the cpanel,, for example:

www.yourwebsite.com/cpanel
Then inter username and password,
Then open 'phpmyadmin' and it contains all the databases and tables of the moodle..

[Find information about moodle er diagrams and tables here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Database_schema_introduction)

Comment: I just need the table where I see what tasks were viewed, I do not know what this table is and I know enter the phpmyadmin ...

Comment: Please check the updates, I just put a link about moodle tables

Answer (score 0):

You can check mdl_course_modules_completion. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be in comment